# Restrict access to static s3 site based on client browser

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, browser

I have a s3 hosted static website that I only want users on Internet Explorer to be able to access. Is this possible?

Comment: _WHY_ do you wish to do this? What is your actual desired outcome that you are wanting to achieve (as opposed to _how_)?

Comment: @Zombie accepting an answer helps everyone in the community

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. It is not possible to restrict access to Amazon S3 based upon the client's browser. Also, please note that it is relatively easy to spoof the browser type, so it is not a good form of security.

Answer (score -1):

To restrict access to content that you serve from Amazon S3 buckets, follow these steps:

Create a special CloudFront user called an origin access identity (OAI) and associate it with your distribution.

Configure your S3 bucket permissions so that CloudFront can use the OAI to access the files in your bucket and serve them to your users. Make sure that users can’t use a direct URL to the S3 bucket to access a file there.

refer: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-restricting-access-to-s3.html